# Using CLOB datatype in SQL stored procedure

Tags: sql, db2, clob

I am calling an DB2 SQL stored procedure (which is in mainframes) with a CLOB datatype as out parameter among other parameters.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ACT_GETAUDIT01                                     
       (                                                            
        IN IN_ID            CHAR(12) FOR SBCS DATA CCSID EBCDIC  
       ,IN IN_CURSOR_ID        INTEGER                              
       ,IN IN_PAGING_TS        CHAR(26) FOR SBCS DATA CCSID EBCDIC  
       ,OUT OUT_AUDTDATA  CLOB FOR SBCS DATA CCSID EBCDIC           
       )


   LANGUAGE SQL                                                 
   READS SQL DATA
```

When calling this stored procedure from JAVA, I get the following exception in the `execute()` statement.

```
CallableStatement cs =  conn.prepareCall(callstmt);

boolean resultsavailable = cs.execute();
```

> *Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Negative initial size: -5*
>       at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.(Unknown Source)
>       at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.ba.a(ba.java:780)
>       at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.bd.d(bd.java:1961)
>       at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.bd.l(bd.java:378)
>       at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.bd.e(bd.java:91)
>       at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.r.e(r.java:108)
>       at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.bs.i(bs.java:191)
>       at com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.cw.o(cw.java:1213)
>       at com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.cx.d(cx.java:2061)
>       at com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.cy.bq(cy.java:145)
>       at com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.cy.execute(cy.java:128)

When I use `VARCHAR` instead of CLOB, everything seems to work fine. I have also have registered the out parameters properly. Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: I haven't worked on DB2. How about specifying the size of CLOB out variable?

Comment: Thanks shahkalpesh. I tried giving OUT OUT_AUDTDATA  CLOB(5000) FOR SBCS DATA CCSID EBCDIC . But I get the same error again

Comment: From the exception , I could only interpret that when the Clob is being processed by the DB2 driver class methods the negative index prevents it from extracting the data. I double checked the Stored procedure as well as the calling java module for any negative values being set. But they are clean. can someone tell me if I am missing something in my analysis

Comment: The issue was that I had outdated DB2 JDBC jarfiles. Now I added updated jar files for my project in eclipse (matching the db2 version I am running) and it worked fine. Please refer to http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21363866 for the DB2 versions and their corresponding JDBC jar files.

Comment: TRy to give us a complete answer, because it seems you solved the problem

Comment: The installed DB2 version was DB2 V10 for ZOS but I used the JDBC drivers meant for DB2 V9. Hence using the correct version of drivers solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

The sqlExe utility has support for handling CLOB fields. You could take a look at it. The source is available here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlexe/